# How do I pass WordPress's get_bloginfo('siteurl') to Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm guessing this is a really dumb question, but I'm far more familiar with PHP/WordPress and I'm just getting started with jQuery so I'm not even sure what to search on. Is there a way to pass the output of

```
echo get_blogifo('siteurl')
```

To jQuery? I'm trying to get this to work:

```
$('a.getstarted').attr('href', '<?php echo get_bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/payroll-deduction-authorization/?plan=basic');
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't use `get_bloginfo` or `bloginfo`, there's a great function called `home_url()`

Comment: Why can't you use bloginfo ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass variables to the front end so that you can pick them by javascript.

Use it like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
$data = array( 'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $data );
```

And pick it up like `object_name.some_string` in javascript code.

Comment: Thank you!! Another really dumb question - how do I actually use that variable? I have the alert working so I know that part's good. I just have no clue how to add it to my line: $('a.getstarted').attr('href', my_home_object.my_home_url'/payroll-deduction-authorization/?plan=basic');

Comment: Nevermind - figured it out! I am feeling the jQuery love. :) $('a.getstarted').attr('href', my_home_object.my_home_url+'/payroll-deduction-authorization/?plan=basic');

Comment: this does not work on twenty theleve child theme.